# Should I use babel or webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks

I have been recently working on a really small frontend framework just to understand how they work. The first thing I started working on is a custom compiler that takes some html code but using my custom syntax and returns JavaScript code that can be executed to render elements (kind of like jsx)

So this is an example and keep in mind that a file can contain only html code.

```
<main>
 <h1 bind:click={someFunction}>Hello</h1>
 <ul (if:condition)>
   <li (each:arr)>
     <p>
       This is going to be rendered multiple time depening on the length of a
       variable called arr
     </p>
   </li>
   {"some js code" ? "here" : "there"}
 </ul>
 <navbar-custom></navbar-custom>
</main>
```

The output after compilation will be:

```
Fore.createElement(
  "main",
  null,
  Fore.createElement("h1", { "bind:click": someFunction }, "Hello"),
  Fore.createElement(
    "ul",
    null,
    [{"IF":confition}],
    Fore.createElement(
      "li",
      null,
      Fore.createElement(
        "p",
        null,
        [{"each":arr}],
        "This is going to be rendered multiple time depening on the length of avariable called arr"
      )
    ),
    "some js code" ? "here" : "there"
  ),
  Fore.createElement("navbar-custom", null, null)
);
```

The compiler is not nearly done but it does the job, so what should I do to get the source from a custom file say app.fore that only contains custom html and use either babel or webpack or smth to transpile the source using my compiler and let babel or idk handle the rest...?

Comment: The two aren't mutually-exclusive; there are any number of ways this could be handled. You might want to *start* by basing it off something like [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) because some of the work is already done, although since you're not actually using an HTML syntax you'd need to work around that. Personally I would stick w/ a syntax that's still valid HTML since it makes using existing tooling not break.

Comment: But i want that custom syntax like angular for example but different, and i have already made a compiler for this but i just need a way to insert it into js files. I tried it using a custom webpack loader but it didnt work as expected especially for custom made components

Comment: Angular syntax is still valid HTML, just with custom props. In any case, that doesn’t change what I said; mechanism is the same, it’s just that HTML tooling will puke.

Comment: Thank you for the help but i still dont get where to use the small compiler that i made. Take this expression for example (each:arr) that cant be valid html so things like this that made me make a compiler, so that is why i asked because i could have just used jsx that would have been alot easier for me but i wanted to try smth new

Comment: My point about HTML syntax is so you can actually use an HTML editor; syntax for the sake of “something different” is fine, but the choice of syntax is arbitrary—you could implement it yourself regardless. I pointed you at the Babel JSX plug-in because that’s an example of how to do a Babel transformer.

Comment: Oh so what I should be looking for is Babel transformer ? like a custom plugin ?

Comment: That's one option; you might also be able to create a webpack loader.

Comment: yeah I tried that but had a huge problem with custom components that also have html inside of them so I didn't really know how to handle it

Comment: Follow the shell of an existing loader; I also don't know how a transforming loader works, but can't be that difficult. (Famous last words.)